# How can I increase the vector size?

Tags: r, memory, vector, size

I wish to solve the "cannot allocate vector of size..." problem with R, in order to load large datasets in R, can someone help me??
I heard someone saying to write "--max-vsize=500M", but I'didn't understand where to write it.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: The `--max-vsize=500M` is a command-line argument. If you launch `R` from the command line, you can use it by doing `R --max-vsize=500M`.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to clear up your workspace, which you can do with the gc() function (i.e. garbage collection)

Along those lines, this will tell you the sizes of your objects, so you can remove objects you don't need any more

```
object.sizes <- function(obs=ls(envir=.GlobalEnv))

{

return(rev(sort(sapply(obs, function (object.name) object.size(get(object.name))))))

}

pie(object.sizes(), main="Memory usage by object")
```

Answer (score 3):

Page 15 of 'The R Inferno' (at http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf ) gives three possibilities for what to do when you get such a message:

1. Don't be a glutton by using bad programming constructs.
2. Get a bigger computer.
3. Reduce the problem size.

A very common way to waste memory is to grow objects -- that's Circle 2 of the Inferno.

These days "bigger computer" may mean moving to 64-bits.